# How to add a constraint which stops a column having two of the same value for only some specified values in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

Basically I have a column which can have one of a set of allowed values (enforced with a foreign key). For some of these values, it is ok for arbitrarily many rows to hold the value. For others, only one row should hold the value at a time.

The schema is too large to paste it here, but an illustrative example would be as follows:

```
name    is_president
Trump   true
Obama   false
Bush    false
```

So only one row can have `is_president = true` while it doesn't matter how many rows have `is_president = false`.

How could I go about enforcing this behaviour? I thought about using a check constraint like:

```
CHECK((SELECT count(*) FROM presidents WHERE is_president = true) <= 1 )
```

but Postgres doesn't allow subqueries inside check constraints.

I'm pretty sure I can get it done with a function, but since I'm very new to schema design I'm especially interested in what the "best practice" solution to such a problem is since it seems like it must be a common case and intuitively I think there must be an elegant solution.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filtered (conditional) unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_is_president on t(is_president) where is_president;
```